# how to create hotspot in Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS no desktop version

Tags: server, 20.04, raspberrypi

I have installed ubuntu server in raspberry pi 3b+ and I'm not getting any proper documentation to do the same, I tried many configuration referring some docs i found but nothing helped so, can someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseicly all you need to do is this edit this file with
`sudo nano /etc/netplan/10-my-config.yaml`

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "SSID":
          password: "your password here"
          mode: ap
```

fill out the `SSID` and the password parts
note the wifi device may change use `ip addr`  figure it out

and run this to apply

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: ERROR: wlan1: Galaxy M31: networkd does not support this wifi mode

this is the error i'm getting

Comment: i also want to assign static ip to it

Comment: update: I resolved the error but I can't find any hotspot which i created

Comment: When you log in to the wifi network the IP is static. For me it was 10.42.0.1 for the pi

Comment: is network manager installed? `sudo apt install network-manager`

Comment: it is working you are right it gives a static ip, the one doubt i have now is if i change the network will it affect the hotspot?

Comment: Also is it possible to change this IP address

Comment: By "i change the network will it affect the hotspot"  if you mean the ssid no it will not by ether net also no

Comment: yeah I tested it and thank you, after experimenting I found way to change IP address I'll post it in answers

Answer (score 2):

Note this answer was copied from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/109427/edit)

Ubuntu Server uses [Netplan](https://netplan.io) to manage its connections.

To create an access point using Netplan, you can do the following:

#### 1. Install Network Manager

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager
```

#### 2. Disable cloud-init

```sh
sudo bash -c "echo 'network: {config: disabled}' > /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg"
```

#### 3. Create a Netplan configuration

```sh
sudo nano /etc/netplan/10-my-config.yaml
```

Then add the following configuration:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "Raspberry":
          password: "your password here"
          mode: ap
```

You can change the access point name "Raspberry" and the password to your liking.

Then save the file using `CTRL+X`.

#### 4. Apply the Netplan configuration

Finally, use use the following commands to apply your new configuration:

```sh
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

A new wireless access point should be created. It has DHCP and DNS enabled by default, and if the Pi has internet access over Ethernet, it'll be shared over the WiFi hotspot as well.

---

For more information about the configuration used in the YAML file, check out the [**Netplan Reference**](https://netplan.io/reference).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the IP of the hotspot which is 10.42.0.1 by default then edit addresses in the `.yaml` file in `/etc/netplan`

```
network:
renderer: NetworkManager
ethernets:
    eth0:
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
version: 2
wifis:
    wlan0:
        dhcp4: true
        access-points:
            "SSID":
                password: "PASSWORD"
                mode: ap
        addresses:
          - 00.00.00.00/24
```